# How to get OObjectDatabaseTx from ConnectionPool?

Tags: orientdb

According OrientDB official doc, I should create Connection Pool with Object API with following code.

```
// OPEN THE DATABASE
OObjectDatabaseTx db= OObjectDatabasePool.global().acquire("remote:localhost/petshop", "admin", "admin");
```

However, I found that OObjectDatabasePool class has been deprecated and suggested to use **com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool** instead.

But in that way, how can I get OObjectDatabaseTx object? That is because OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire() can only return ODatabaseDocumentTx object.

Hope there are someone knows how to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Xianyi, which OrientDB version are you using ?

Comment: @LucaS The version I used is 2.1.13

Comment: @XianyiYe, i edited the previous answer, adding the code to get "OObjectDatabaseTx" from "OPartitionedDatabasePool". I think this is more near to what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code you can get "object to connect to" and then make queries etc.

**GET DOCUMENT DB**

```
String remote = "remote:localhost/";
    String nameDB = "domain"; 
    String url = remote + nameDB;
    OPartitionedDatabasePool pool = new OPartitionedDatabasePool(url, "admin", "admin");
    ODatabaseDocumentTx db = pool.acquire();

    //use example 
    List<ODocument> resultset = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<Object>("select from ORole"));

    for(ODocument doc:resultset) {
        System.out.println(doc);
    }   
    db.close();
```

**GET OBJECT DB**

```
String remote = "remote:localhost/";
    String nameDB = "TestPartitioned2"; 
    String url = remote + nameDB;

    OServerAdmin serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(url).connect("root", "root");
    serverAdmin.createDatabase(nameDB, "object", "plocal");
    System.out.println(" Database '"+nameDB +"' created!..");

    OPartitionedDatabasePool pool = new OPartitionedDatabasePool(url, "admin", "admin");

    //object
    OObjectDatabaseTx db = new OObjectDatabaseTx(pool.acquire());

    db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(Person.class);
    Person personA = db.newInstance(Person.class);
    personA.setName("tennantA");
    db.save(personA);
    db.close();
```

Comment: @ lsavio That is what I want and it's really awesome! Thanks for your quick help!!